# Tensorflow-GPU on WSL2 not working

Tags: cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tensorflow

Is there any way to install [tensorflow-gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) on WSL2?
After trying to set up CUDA on WSL and running `nvidia-smi`, it had the error:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

If anyone knows how to fix it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq#can-i-access-the-gpu-in-wsl-2-are-there-plans-to-increase-hardware-support):
"In initial releases of WSL 2 hardware access support will be limited, e.g: you will be unable to access the GPU...".

**Update June 18, 2020**:

"What’s new in Build 20150
Three new Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) features: GPU compute, WSL install, and WSL update"
https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/158773-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20150-1000-rs_prerelease-june-17-a.html

Comment: excited about the release of WSL 2, installed and tried then disappointed about the unavailable support of GPU access ....

Comment: @Franva  It will be released soon. 

"... we’re thrilled to announce that we will start previewing GPU compute support for WSL in Windows 10 Insider builds within the next few months!"

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-build-2020-summary/#wsl-gpu

Comment: GPU access is now available to WSL2 users who are on the Fast Insider ring. I can confirm that GPU access does work to some degree. It feels alpha quality as today.

Comment: @BSalita Did you install Tensorflow-GPU on WSL2? If so, can you please share how?

Comment: @A.Hendry follow the instruction of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnK1jO2kXOQ
I confirm that it works at the time of this post.

Comment: @FariborzGhavamian My setup uses an eGPU over Thunderbolt 3. This is different than the video. I have an NVIDIA Titan V connected to a Dell Precision 7540 through a Razor Core X Chroma eGPU using Thunderbolt3. The card is detected by Tensorflow 2.3 in Windows, but Docker in Ubuntu-18.04 LTS says it cannot find the GPU. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

WSL is not designed to provide a full spectrum Linux experience, and is limited in ways Microsoft only knows how, but we're finding out. The well accepted method to run Linux under another OS is virtualization, such as VirtualBox or other virtual machine systems.